# SSL enabling for rabbitmq mangement. Server starts, but fails to accept requests

Tags: plugins, openssl, rabbitmq

Followed the instructions for creating an SSL set of files with a self signed certificate according to rabbit [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

I am using it for the management plugin instead only for now, by configuring rabbitmq.config like:

> {rabbitmq_management,       [ {http_log_dir,  "/tmp/rabbit-mgmt"},
>
> ```
>                             {rates_mode,    basic},
>
>                             {listener, [{port,     7357},
>
>                                         {ssl,      true},
>
>                                         {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/ca_certificate.pem"},
>                                                     {certfile,   "/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
>                                                     {keyfile,    "/path/to/server_key.pem"},
>                                                     {verify,verify_peer},
>                                                     {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}
>                                                    ]}
>                                        ]}
>                           ]}
> ```

The server starts, and the https port seems open, however, the connection fails as soon as a request is received with:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 25-Sep-2015::14:25:33 ===
>       application: mochiweb
>       "Accept failed error"
>       "{error,{options,{cacertfile,\"/path/to/ca_certificate.pem\",\n                            {error,eacces}}}}"
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 25-Sep-2015::14:25:33 === {mochiweb_socket_server,295,{acceptor_error,{error,accept_failed}}}

I tried `chown` and `chgrp` of the folders that have all the certificate files created by following the documentation, but still have the same access error.

Comment: Where you put your certs?

Comment: They were in a correct path, but the parent path folder didn´t have permissions. It was hard to tell since the error, didn´t specify which folder was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to file permissions, the folders were all granting rabbitmq read access, but they were inside another folder without access.

Comment: Yup, that's what `error,eacces` means. In Erlang whenever you get an `{error, esomething}` message, try googling for the `esomething` since that's usually a POSIX error

Comment: Thanks old_sound that's how I got the answer, but it wasn't at the very first link of the results.

Comment: Thanks, BTW this is what I did, `chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/letsencrypt/live && chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/letsencrypt/archive`